# How can I join all rows data in one row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I join all rows data in one row? With a SQL query please.

SELECT *
FROM Tasks;

| Name | Day |
| --- | --- |
| Joseph | Morning |
| Karem | Afternoon |
| Anthony | Evening |
| John | Morning |

The result will be, all united

| Name | Day |
| --- | --- |
| Joseph Karem Anthony John | Morning Afternoon Evening Morning |

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: To define the separator: `GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR ',')` (there are even more options - look it up)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Name) AS Names, GROUP_CONCAT(Day) AS Days FROM Tasks
```